# Update Notes on SOOrder CustomerID change

Tags: acumatica

When a new sales order is created and the customer assigned, the notes from the customer master record need to be injected into the sales order notes.

I am able to acomplish this only on save the Sales Order, but I need to do it before the Sales Order is save.

Thanks in advance!

So far I have tried searching for a way to change the Notes attributes to CommitChanges to true,and  Update on CustomerID field Updated.